# How to group failed APIs in Report with different parameters while using FastHttp in Locust

Tags: python, python-requests, gevent, locust

My API is like /api/v1/users/checkuser?PhoneNo
I am creating requests for random phone nos. When I am using HttpUser(Requests) it shows grouped results whenever API failed for any number. But when is use FastHttpuser(geventhttpclient) it shows failed APIs in different columns for different phone nos.
I already used name to group APIs. But it only grouping in Statistics not in Failed part.
self.client.get(f"/api/v1/users/checkuser?phone_number={self.phone_no}", name="/api/v1/users/checkuser")

Answer (score 0):

Passing in `name="/api/v1/users/checkuser?phone_number"`  or whatever for your requests should make Locust use that for reporting and such instead which should group them together. That's supposed to be compatible with FastHttp as well. Here's the doc page for it.

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/increase-performance.html

Perhaps try using the `request()` call instead?

`self.client.request("get", f"/api/v1/users/checkuser?phone_number={self.phone_no}", name="/api/v1/users/checkuser")`

Comment: self.client.client calls self.client.request with all its parameters so it's the same, the issue is not solved with name because in the Failures report the Error Type shows the URL instead of the name parameter. You can see this issue only with FastHttpUser